# Can not start container in Drools workbench when rules generated from spreadsheet

Tags: drools, kie-workbench

In a project of Drools workbench, when rules are input with "**Guided Rule**", I can start the container correctly. But when rules are **generated from spreadsheet (an *.xls file)**, I got the following error:

```
org.kie.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl createContainer
SEVERE: Error creating container 'firstApplicationTestCon' for module 'ppdrools:firstApplicationTestProj:1.0'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate service for Class 'org.drools.compiler.compiler.DecisionTableProvider'
```

Did I miss something? Why did I fail to start the container while I can build the project successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it's a known bug. See the posts below:

[[ENG] (6.1.z) Decision Table Spreadsheet on Execution Server](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1217296)

[BZ-1214927: adding decision tables jar dependency to kie-server](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-integration/commit/7bc2b42c9e887b0b6747f7c622c34dcfb0c2ca5a)

And a duplicated bug report here on 2015-05-28:

[Bug 1225979 - Kie sever starting error - ClassNotFoundException: org.drools.decisiontable.DecisionTableProviderImpl](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1225979#c3)

Since this bug is reported and verified after 2015-03-05, which is the day 6.2 released, I think it's not solved yet. I'll have a try on 6.3.0.Beta2 later.

Comment: BTW, I found it's firstly reported on google groups: [Unable to instantiate service for Class 'org.drools.compiler.compiler.DecisionTableProvider'](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/drools-setup/OrxBvtV-K20/FXEqfc4iez4J)